# Collecting external div

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, rss

I want to show my feed on my site (sn0wy0wl.com), but I currently upload my data to RSSPECT.com.

I have managed to show the entire RSSPECT feed page, but I just want it to show specifically the Div div#feedBody this is surely possible, I've just had no luck so far.

My current code for this:

```
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:400px; overflow: auto;">
<object type="text/html" data="http://www.rsspect.com/rss/feedtestfilename.xml"
 style="width:100%; height:400px; margin:1px;">
</object>
</div>
```

Comment: How about `data="http://www.rsspect.com/rss/feedtestfilename.xml#feedBody"`. Not sure about xml, but you can do like this with html.

Comment: @Morpheus — that will cause the browser to *scroll* to that point, not show only that data.

Comment: @Quentin maybe I've mistaken about html, but surely it can be done with jQuery ([example](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

Comment: @Morpheus — The jQuery load method does work that way (but comes with a stack of gotchas)

Comment: Then would I add something like this instead of the <object>?:
`<script>
$("#feedBody").load("http://www.rsspect.com/rss/feedtestfilename.xml");
</script>`

Comment: It would be: `<script>$(document).ready(function{ $('#YOURDIV').load("http://www.rsspect.com/rss/feedtestfilename.xml #feedBody");});</script>`. Don't forget to include jQuery in your `head` section.

Comment: @Morpheus Thank you for sticking with this, though I may be pushing it now with asking of your help, the code doesn't seem to work or I'm doing something wrong. In my <head>:  
`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>`  
in my <body> `<div id="fof"><script>$(document).ready(function{ $('#fof').load("http://www.rsspect.com/rss/feedtestfilename.xml #feedBody");});</script></div>`  
and <css>: `#fof{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 400px;
 overflow: auto;
}`

Comment: The `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` broke my accordian, but more to the point, there is no longer a '400px high container for the external content, so I guess I have not properly arranged some code for this to have happened

Comment: Change `$(document).ready(function` to `$(document).ready(function()`. Look at console log, you should see errors like this one.

Comment: Thanks @Morpheus, now I have the designated space showing up on my site with nothing loading in it. Again, `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>` still breaks my other javascripts, perhaps it conflicts with my local `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>`, though removing this doesn't fix the script to output the div as we worked on. I wonder if this is even viable.